# many OID's for interface and others on SFP

Tags: python, snmp, huawei-mobile-services, pysnmp

When I do snmpwalk on interface I get multiple duplicate descriptions:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get ifIndex only active interfaces? No duplicates?

And:
[image]

Why does the SFP module have this ID (.17236997)? As it is assigned to Gigabitethernet0/3/4 ??

[image]

I am writing a script in python (pysnmp) and looking for OIDs for specific interface parameters.
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Please read the related MIB documents to understand those OIDs first. Don't draw any conclusion based on what you got from WALK operation.

Comment: @LexLi - I found ifnformations about this GigabitEthernet0/3/2.XXX - there are VLAN's
but I can't find information regarding the SFP modules ID.

Are you able to help with this?

Comment: Your best resource is the vendor of the device at this moment.

Comment: What Vendor? Juniper? Cisco? ???  Look for a "hardware", "chassis", and/or "inventory" type MIB(s) to see SFPs.  This is a vendor specific question--open a ticket with them.  You can read the MIBs yourself, but it can be laborious and tricky.  The dups are probably the intfs at layers 1, 2, 3... 
 (SNMP does not always get all you need; sometimes you need CLI/shell cmds.)

Answer (score 0):

Those other intfs are sub-intfs--refer to the ifStackTable in RFC2863